# i am using spring for hibernate only not as spring mvc and i am using jsf2.0 and now i need to implement AOP

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsf, jsf-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement AOP with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203018/how-to-implement-aop-with-spring)

i am using spring for hibernate only not as spring mvc and i am using jsf2.0 and now i need to implement AOP but I am not getting at what to do i am not following Spring MVC..

Comment: Please don't repost the same question because you didn't get good answers with the previous one. Work on your question, the problem is not the answsers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You* don't need to implement AOP - Spring already does that.

You sound like you're asking how to express [declarative transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html) in Spring.  Best to look at the Spring docs.

Spring doesn't require that you use it everywhere in your apps.  You are free to use it for Hibernate and not use Spring MVC if you choose.